# How to call a XIB and return to the calling XIB?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xib, xcode6.1, ios8.1

I have an app with two (2) XIB files; one is the main view, the other is a help view.  I have view controllers created for both.  I have a button on the main view XIB that calls the help view which works like this:

```
- (IBAction)bDisplayHelp:(UIButton *)sender {

HelpViewController *svc = [HelpViewController new];
svc = [[HelpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview: svc.view];
```

}

On the Help view, I have a button which I want to take the user back to the Main view.  This is my code (which is not working):

```
- (IBAction)bBackToMainNib:(UIButton *)sender {

MainViewController *tvc = [MainViewController new];
tvc = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview: tvc.view];
```

}

All I did was essentially go back and forth.  I'm getting this error at runtime when I attempt to return to the Main view (doesn't execute the first statement, just crashes):

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString bBackToMainNib:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d3586b0'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you calling the method bBackToMainNib?

Comment: it's an actiion on a UIButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, but you're doing pretty much everything wrong. First of all, your first line in bDisplayHelp: is useless since you redefine svc in the next line (you have the same problem in bBackToMainNib:). Replace those two lines with,

```
HelpViewController *svc = [[HelpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Secondly, you bBackToMainNib: method doesn't go back to the main controller, it creates a new instance of the main view controller.

Thirdly, you shouldn't be adding the view of one controller to the view of another, unless you also add that controller as a child view controller (otherwise the view controller will be deallocated). You should probably present (and then dismiss when you want to go back) HelpViewController, rather than adding its view as a subview (although, since I don't know what your intent is, this might not be the best option). I suggest you read the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" to understand the basic paradigms of iOS programming.

As to your actual error, that's a mystery. The error message is saying that you're calling bBackToMainNib: on a string, not your controller; I'm not sure how that can happen.

Comment: Thank you... I have never worked with XIBs before, always used Storyboards, and thought this would be a good exercise.  I appreciate your detailed answer, will make it easier for me to re-design this part of the app.